# In DataFactory, is there a solution to load data into Dynamics365 using the web API?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I need to upload registers into Dynamics365 using an AZDF pipeline. 
Because of some requirements, I need to load the data through the web API.

I thought of using Functions/Durable Functions. They can use the API with no problem, but I'm concerned about the duration of the execution since I understand that these activities are not meant for long runs, like downloading/loading data, etcetera.

Is it really wrong to use a Functions like this?
Is there an alternative?

Comment: Maybe you can put it into answer field and then mark it as answer so that someone else can find it easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In DataFactory, what is a good strategy to migrate data into Dynamics365 using Dynamics Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908297/in-datafactory-what-is-a-good-strategy-to-migrate-data-into-dynamics365-using-d)