# In DataFactory, what is a good strategy to migrate data into Dynamics365 using Dynamics Web API?

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I need to migrate data using DataFactory to Dynamics365. The Dynamics365 connector is not enough for me since one of the requirements is to only update those attributes that have been modified since last migration - not the whole register. The other requirement is that sometimes we have to 'null' values in destination.

I believe that I can do that by generating a different JSON for register and migrate them using the Web API.

I thought in putting these calls in an Azure Functions, but I believe that they are not meant to be used like this - even though with the right pricing plan they can run with no limit of time.

I think I'm doing it wrong and I can't figure out the right way.

Could you share your experience or point of view?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to interact with Dynamics 365 from other application is either directly with the WebAPI or using C#'s SDK, in both scenarios, for create or update multiple records the best way to do it (as far as i know) is using [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-executemultiple-improve-performance-bulk-data-load) Message, this allow you to set it with updates, creates, deletes and execute then in one request.